# android passing a id from one activity to list activity

Tags: php, android, android-intent

Hye!! 
I have a activity from which the id from employee should be taken and passed to the other activity . The Problem is it doesnt not only take the id but it also takes the other content of Employee Details .. but it should only take ID !! I have no clue how to do this!! Please help

For example : In Employee_Details_Activity :When a button is click in Employee Activity, it should take only the emloyee id and pass to the Time Activity(where each working time of emplyoee should be shown. As shown it this figure!!

Note : Employee Details Activity = a normal activity and Time Activity is a List View!! 
It should pass me only the id and the time is parsed from PHP

I cant show any images because i m new here!!

Comment: Actually you need to pass some value from one android activity to another activity. Am i currect?

Comment: can you provide some code of yours?

Comment: @user2171751 if some of the answers help you please accept them so this question doesn't go to unanswered section.

Comment: @SibirajPR , yes i need to pass a value from one activity to a list activity

Answer (score 0):

use intents: In first activity use

```
intent.putExtra("Title", listTitleString);
intent.putExtra("Content", listDescriptionString);
startActivity(intent);
```

In second activity use:

```
title= getIntent().getExtras().getString("Title");
```

Comment: the best part is whether i m using Intent or not.. it passing the last activity details to the new one!!